# Error al usar un recurso anidado 'undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy tratando de hacer funcionar un recurso anidado pero me quede atascado; obtengo un error al tratar de crear una nueva 'prescripcion', por favor si alguien puede ayudarme a identificar lo que esta sucediendo se lo agradecería.

Saludos!

**Error:**
    undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass

```
def new
  @prescription = @prescription.new
end
```

[image: Error]

**Rutas:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :patients, shallow: true do
    resources :consultations do
      resources :prescriptions
    end 
  end
end
```

**Vista desde la cual se genera '/prescriptions/new'**

```
<%= link_to 'New Prescription', new_consultation_prescription_path(@consultation) %>
<%= link_to 'Show Prescriptions', consultation_prescriptions_path(@consultation) %>
```

**Controlador 'Prescriptions':**

```
class PrescriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_consultation
  before_action :set_prescription, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @prescription = Prescriptions.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @prescription = @prescription.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @prescription = @prescription.new(prescription_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @prescription.save
        format.html { redirect_to @prescription, notice: 'Prescription was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @prescription }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @prescription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_consultation
      @consultation = Consultation.find_by_id(params[:id])
    end

    def set_prescription
      @prescription = Prescription.find(params[:id])
    end

    def prescription_params
      params.require(:prescription).permit(:prescription, :consultation_id)
    end
end
```

**Modelo 'Prescription':**

```
class Prescription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :consultation, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**Form 'Prescription':**

```
<%= form_for([@consultation, @prescription]) do |f| %>
  <% if @prescription.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@prescription.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this prescription from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @prescription.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :prescription %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :prescription %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :consultation_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :consultation_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma que usas para inicializar el objeto de prescripción es incorrecta. 
Debería ser `@prescription = Prescription.new`

Comment: Es correcto, ya lo corregí como tu indicas y en efecto me deja avanzar a la vista 'new' el problema ahora es que no me muestra la tabla con los botones Edit, Show, Delete. es como si no estuviese cargando el parcial del _form, el form lo hice así: `<% form_for prescription_path(@prescription, @consultation) do |f| %>` y me tira este error: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :consultation_id=>"1", :controller=>"prescriptions", :id=>#<Prescription id: nil, prescription: nil, consultation_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>} missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: @CarlosGómez hay veces en que siendo mas explícito en el ingreso de parámetros resulta. Prueba con  `prescription_path(id: @prescription, consultation_id: @consultation)` o con `prescription_path(id: @prescription.id, consultation_id: @consultation.id)`. Si ninguna resulta, ejecuta `rake routes` para comparar que la ruta generada por rails es la que efectivamente estas usando.

Comment: @CarlosGómez si la respuesta te fue útil, puedes marcarla como aceptada. Saludos